# Solid angle formula

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

How do you get from the equation on the left to the one on the right?
  $$  \Omega = \iint_S \frac { \vec{r} \cdot \hat{n} \,dS }{r^3}= \iint_S \sin\theta\,d\theta\,d\varphi . $$

Thanks.

Comment: I assume $S$ is a unit sphere?

Answer (score 1):

It comes from the representation of the $S$ in spherical coordinates:

$$dS = r^2 \sin{\theta}\,d\theta \, d\phi$$

Note that $\vec{r} \cdot \vec{n} = r$, because for a sphere, the normal is a radial line.

Comment: But where does the $dr$ go, as it's only a double integral?

Comment: My mistake - there is no $dr$ term on a surface.  The integral through a volume of a sphere of radius $R$, though, is $$\int_0^R dr \int_{\partial S} dS.

Comment: How do you get the formula for $dS$? It looks like the Jacobian for spherical coordinates, would the process be similar to that?

Comment: It is the Jacobian for spherical, except that you are on a surface,